# Threading across multiple files

Tags: c, multithreading

My program is reading in files and using thread to compute the highest prime number, when I put a print statement into the getNum() function my numbers are printing out. However, it seems to just lag no matter how many threads I input.  Each file has 1 million integers in it.  Does anyone see something apparently wrong with my code? Basically the code is giving each thread 1000 integers to check before assigning a new thread.  I am still a C noobie and am just learning the ropes of threading. My code is a mess right now because I have been switching things around constantly.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//Global variable declaration
char *file1 = "primes1.txt";
char *file2 = "primes2.txt";
char *file3 = "primes3.txt";
char *file4 = "primes4.txt";
char *file5 = "primes5.txt";
char *file6 = "primes6.txt";
char *file7 = "primes7.txt";
char *file8 = "primes8.txt";
char *file9 = "primes9.txt";
char *file10 = "primes10.txt";

char **fn; //file name variable

int numberOfThreads;
int *highestPrime = NULL;
int fileArrayNum = 0;
int loop = 0;

int currentFile = 0;


sem_t semAccess;
sem_t semAssign;

int prime(int n)//check for prime number, return 1 for prime 0 for nonprime
{
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    if(n % i == 0)
      return(0);

    return(1);
}

int getNum(FILE* file)
{
  int number;
  char* tempS = malloc(20 *sizeof(char));
  fgets(tempS, 20, file);
  tempS[strlen(tempS)-1] = '\0';
  number = atoi(tempS);


  free(tempS);//free memory for later call

  return(number);
}

void* findPrimality(void *threadnum) //main thread function to find primes
{
  int tNum = (int)threadnum;
  int checkNum;
  char *inUseFile = NULL;
  int x=1;

  FILE* file;
  while(currentFile < 10){

    if(inUseFile == NULL){//inUseFIle being used to check if a file is still being read

      sem_wait(&semAccess);//critical section     
      inUseFile = fn[currentFile];
      sem_post(&semAssign);
      file = fopen(inUseFile, "r");


      while(!feof(file)){
    if(x % 1000 == 0 && tNum !=1){ //go for 1000 integers and then wait
      sem_wait(&semAssign);
    }

    checkNum = getNum(file);
    /*
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * I think the issue is here
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    if(checkNum > highestPrime[tNum]){
      if(prime(checkNum)){
        highestPrime[tNum] = checkNum;
      }
    }

    x++;
      }
      fclose(file);
      inUseFile = NULL;
    }
    currentFile++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if(argc != 2){ //checks for number of arguements being passed
printf("To many ARGS\n");
return(-1);
  }
  else{//Sets thread cound to user input checking for correct number of threads
    numberOfThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(numberOfThreads < 1 || numberOfThreads > 10){
      printf("To many threads entered\n");
      return(-1);
    }

    time_t preTime, postTime; //creating time variables

    int i;

    fn = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*)); //create file array and initialize

    fn[0] = file1;
    fn[1] = file2;
    fn[2] = file3;
    fn[3] = file4;
    fn[4] = file5;
    fn[5] = file6;
    fn[6] = file7;
    fn[7] = file8;
    fn[8] = file9;
    fn[9] = file10;


    sem_init(&semAccess, 0, 1); //initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&semAssign, 0, numberOfThreads);

    highestPrime = malloc(numberOfThreads * sizeof(int)); //create an array to store each threads highest number

    for(loop = 0; loop < numberOfThreads; loop++){//set initial values to 0
      highestPrime[loop] = 0;   
    }

    pthread_t calculationThread[numberOfThreads]; //thread to do the work

    preTime = time(NULL); //start the clock

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
      pthread_create(&calculationThread[i], NULL, findPrimality, (void *)i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
      pthread_join(calculationThread[i], NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
      printf("this is a prime number: %d \n", highestPrime[i]);
    }
    postTime= time(NULL);
    printf("Wall time: %ld seconds\n", (long)(postTime - preTime));
  }
}
```

Yes I am trying to find the highest number over all.  So I have made some head way the last few hours, rescucturing the program as spudd said, currently I am getting a segmentation fault due to my use of structures, I am trying to save the largest individual primes in the struct while giving them the right indices.  This is the revised code.  So in short what the first thread is doing is creating all the threads and giving them access points to a very large integer array which they will go through and find prime numbers, I want to implement semaphores around the while loop so that while they are executing every 2000 lines or the end they update a global prime number.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//Global variable declaration
char *file1 = "primes1.txt";
char *file2 = "primes2.txt";
char *file3 = "primes3.txt";
char *file4 = "primes4.txt";
char *file5 = "primes5.txt";
char *file6 = "primes6.txt";
char *file7 = "primes7.txt";
char *file8 = "primes8.txt";
char *file9 = "primes9.txt";
char *file10 = "primes10.txt";



int numberOfThreads;
int entries[10000000];
int entryIndex = 0;
int fileCount = 0;
char** fileName;
int largestPrimeNumber = 0;


//Register functions
int prime(int n);
int getNum(FILE* file);
void* findPrimality(void *threadNum);
void* assign(void *num);

typedef struct package{
  int largestPrime;
  int startingIndex;
  int numberCount;
}pack;



//Beging main code block
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if(argc != 2){ //checks for number of arguements being passed
printf("To many threads!!\n");
return(-1);
  }
  else{ //Sets thread cound to user input checking for correct number of threads
    numberOfThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(numberOfThreads < 1 || numberOfThreads > 10){
      printf("To many threads entered\n");
      return(-1);
    }

    int threadPointer[numberOfThreads]; //Pointer array to point to entries

    time_t preTime, postTime; //creating time variables

    int i;

    fileName = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*)); //create file array and initialize

    fileName[0] = file1;
    fileName[1] = file2;
    fileName[2] = file3;
    fileName[3] = file4;
    fileName[4] = file5;
    fileName[5] = file6;
    fileName[6] = file7;
    fileName[7] = file8;
    fileName[8] = file9;
    fileName[9] = file10;

    FILE* filereader;
    int currentNum;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      filereader = fopen(fileName[i], "r");
      while(!feof(filereader)){
        char* tempString = malloc(20 *sizeof(char));
        fgets(tempString, 20, filereader);
        tempString[strlen(tempString)-1] = '\0';
        entries[entryIndex] = atoi(tempString);
        entryIndex++;
        free(tempString);       
      }
    }

    //sem_init(&semAccess, 0, 1); //initialize semaphores
    //sem_init(&semAssign, 0, numberOfThreads);
    time_t tPre, tPost;



    pthread_t coordinate;

    tPre = time(NULL);
    pthread_create(&coordinate, NULL, assign, (void**)numberOfThreads);
    pthread_join(coordinate, NULL);


    tPost = time(NULL);



  }

}

void* findPrime(void* pack_array)
{
  pack* currentPack=  pack_array;
  int lp = currentPack->largestPrime;
  int si = currentPack->startingIndex;
  int nc = currentPack->numberCount;

  int i;
  int j = 0;


  for(i = si; i < nc; i++){

    while(j < 2000 || i == (nc-1)){

      if(prime(entries[i])){

    if(entries[i] > lp)

      lp = entries[i];
      }

      j++;

    }

  }
   return (void*)currentPack; 
}

void* assign(void* num)
{
  int y = (int)num;
  int i;

  int count = 10000000/y;
  int finalCount = count + (10000000%y);

  int sIndex = 0;



  pack pack_array[(int)num];
  pthread_t workers[numberOfThreads]; //thread to do the workers


  for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
    if(i == (y-1)){
      pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
      pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
      pack_array[i].numberCount = finalCount;
    }

    pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
    pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
    pack_array[i].numberCount = count;


    pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, findPrime, (void *)&pack_array[i]);
    sIndex += count;
  }
  for(i = 0; i< y; i++)
    pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
}




//Functions

int prime(int n)//check for prime number, return 1 for prime 0 for nonprime
{
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    if(n % i == 0)
      return(0);

    return(1);
}
```

Here is my latest update, having issues with my threads running, the only thread is thread 0 that is completing

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//Global variable declaration
char *file1 = "primes1.txt";
char *file2 = "primes2.txt";
char *file3 = "primes3.txt";
char *file4 = "primes4.txt";
char *file5 = "primes5.txt";
char *file6 = "primes6.txt";
char *file7 = "primes7.txt";
char *file8 = "primes8.txt";
char *file9 = "primes9.txt";
char *file10 = "primes10.txt";

sem_t semHold;

int numberOfThreads;
long unsigned int entries[10000000];
unsigned int entryIndex = 0;
int fileCount = 0;
char** fileName;
long unsigned int largestPrimeNumber = 0;


//Register functions
int prime(unsigned int n);
int getNum(FILE* file);
void* findPrimality(void *threadNum);
void* assign(void *num);

typedef struct package{
  long unsigned int largestPrime;
  unsigned int startingIndex;
  unsigned int numberCount;
}pack;

pack pack_array[10];


//Beging main code block
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if(argc != 2){ //checks for number of arguements being passed
printf("To many threads!!\n");
return(-1);
  }
  else{ //Sets thread cound to user input checking for correct number of threads
    numberOfThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(numberOfThreads < 1 || numberOfThreads > 10){
      printf("To many threads entered\n");
      return(-1);
    }

    int threadPointer[numberOfThreads]; //Pointer array to point to entries



    int i;


    fileName = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*)); //create file array and initialize

    fileName[0] = file1;
    fileName[1] = file2;
    fileName[2] = file3;
    fileName[3] = file4;
    fileName[4] = file5;
    fileName[5] = file6;
    fileName[6] = file7;
    fileName[7] = file8;
    fileName[8] = file9;
    fileName[9] = file10;

    FILE* filereader;
    long unsigned int currentNum;

    sem_init(&semHold, 0, 1);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      filereader = fopen(fileName[i], "r");
      while(fscanf(filereader, "%lu" , &currentNum)!= EOF){
    entries[entryIndex] = currentNum;
    // while(entryIndex < 5){
      //char* tempString = malloc(20 *sizeof(long unsigned int));
    //fgets(tempString, 20, filereader);

    //tempString[strlen(tempString)-1] = '\0';

    //currentNum = atoi(tempString);
    //printf("Test %lu\n",currentNum);

    //entries[entryIndex] = atoi(tempString);

    //entryIndex++;

    //free(tempString);       
    //}
    entryIndex++;
    }
  }
  printf("Test %lu\n",entries[9999999]);
  //sem_init(&semAccess, 0, 1); //initialize semaphores
  //sem_init(&semAssign, 0, numberOfThreads);
  time_t tPre, tPost;



  pthread_t coordinate;

  tPre = time(NULL);

  pthread_create(&coordinate, NULL, assign, (void**)numberOfThreads);

  pthread_join(coordinate, NULL);


  tPost = time(NULL);

  printf("Largest prime = %lu , time: %ld\n", largestPrimeNumber,(long)(tPost-tPre));



}

}

void* findPrime(void* pack_array)
{

  pack* currentPack =  pack_array;
  unsigned int lp = currentPack->largestPrime;
  unsigned int si = currentPack->startingIndex;
  unsigned int nc = currentPack->numberCount;

  int i;
  printf("Starting index Count: %d\n", si);
  for(i = si; i < nc; i++){
    if(i%100000==0)
      printf("Here is i: %d\n", i);
    if(entries[i]%2 != 0){
      if(entries[i] > currentPack->largestPrime){      
    if(prime(entries[i])){

      currentPack->largestPrime = entries[i];
      printf("%lu\n", currentPack->largestPrime);

    if(currentPack->largestPrime > largestPrimeNumber)
      sem_wait(&semHold);
      largestPrimeNumber = currentPack->largestPrime;
      sem_post(&semHold);
    }
      }    
    }
  }

}

void* assign(void* num)
{

  int y = (int)num;
  int i;

  int count = 10000000/y;
  int finalCount = count + (10000000%y);

  int sIndex = 0;
  printf("This is count: %d\n", count);
  printf("This is final count: %d\n", finalCount);


  pthread_t workers[y]; //thread to do the workers


  for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
    printf("for thread %d Starting index: %d\n", i, sIndex);
    if(i == (y-1)){
      pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
      pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
      pack_array[i].numberCount = finalCount;
    }

    pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
    pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
    pack_array[i].numberCount = count;


    pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, findPrime, (void *)&pack_array[i]);
    printf("thread created\n");
    sIndex += count;

  }
  for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);

}




//Functions

int prime(unsigned int n)//check for prime number, return 1 for prime 0 for nonprime
{
  int i;
  for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
    if(n % i == 0)
      return(0);

    return(1);
}
```

Comment: semAccess is intitialized to 1 and I don't see you posting it anywhere. This could cause your deadlock. Aren't the initializations of the semaphores switched?

Comment: Sadly I understand none of this and am fighting the urg to give up, what I really need to do is have a coordinator thread handle grabbing blocks of memory aka integers by the 1000's and give them to the worker threads.  But at this point I have no idea how to do this :(

Comment: If I wanted to achieve this, I'd do it like this. Manager thread: while the queue of worker threads is not empty, dequeue the first one, give him work and wake him up. If the queue is empty,  go to sleep. Worker thread. While there is some work to do, do it. If there is  nothing to do, enqueue self and if the queue is empty wake the manager up and finally go to sleep. This seems like a slight modification of producer-consumer problem. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

Comment: All that I want to do at this point is just pass each thread an entire file and let it work through that, if I can implement that i will be happy but I don't know where to start...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help, I understand so little of the syntax needed to achieve that.  It is absolutely pitiful.

Comment: ok, give me a sec, I'll give you a skeleton.

Comment: Actually I gotta leave now, gonna d it in the evening if I have time. Sorry

Comment: I'd like to pop in with a small recommendation here, it'd probably be better to suck all the numbers up in the main thread into one big array, or several small ones in the main thread then pass around indices of blocks to work on or pointers. But making that go fast would require more complex file reading code if you're interested I could also mock up something for you.

Comment: Also I'm not clear on one thing, are you looking for the highest prime over all files or the highest prime in each file individually?

Comment: I see some problems right away, you're never going to read more than the first 1000 numbers from any given file because you open it new each time in the threads

Comment: Also since the current highest prime for each thread doesn't need to be visible outside it use a local variable until the end that'll be faster for reasons that'd be complex to explain but if you care google 'false sharing', but I wouldn't advise it until you're comfortable with C and threading.

Comment: Apart from the threading issues, all even numbers should be eliminated from your primality tests. Furthermore, if the bottom bit is NOT lit on the input value, abort immediately, as it means the number is a multiple of 2 and thus cannot be prime (unless it *is* two, which can be tested *after* determining the bottom bit isn't lit). Your primality test will literally finish in half the time it does now.

Comment: I will implement things to make it faster when I have a program that atleast compiles and doesn't crash :P thanks for the insight though that is a great idea

Comment: If this isn't homework I have a solution for you that I could post as an answer

Comment: This is indeed homework, sorry I thought I had put that at the top.  I am just looking for pointers in the right direction, no pun intended. I am determined to not let this code defeat me, I have new energy to figuring it out!

Comment: you're not doing this on a Mac, by chance, are you? Do yourself a favor and check the return results of each and every `sem_xxxx` API. I ask because 10.8.1 Darwin doesn't support `sem_init()` (though it declares and links with it, it returns "Function not implemented". Even if you're not on a Mac, check *all* function return codes regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's part of my solution, it's missing most of main, and has some other simple stuff missing, if you choose to base your code around this you can do one of two things load all the data before starting your workers, or have the main thread load it while the workers are running, I did the latter in my complete version. However you'll have to do some work to get that to be handled correctly because currently the workers will never exit.

Also you might want to try adapting your single array code above based on this.

So if you load all the data before starting the workers you don't need the condition variable and they can just exit when `next_chunk` is `NULL`. I recommend you figure out how to get loading while the workers are running working because it'll be more efficient.
Hint: `pthread_cond_broadcast()`

Also missing is the actual worker function.

```
// A singly linked list of chunks of 1000 numbers
// we use it as a queue of data to be processed
struct number_chunk
{
    struct number_chunk *next;
    int size;
    int nums[1000];
};

pthread_mutex_t cnklst_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t data_available = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
struct number_chunk *next_chunk = NULL;

void load_chunks(char *filename)
{
    FILE *in = fopen(filename, "r");
    int done = 0;
    int i;

    if(in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    // read in all the chunks of 1000 numbers from the file
    while(!done) {
        struct number_chunk *cnk = malloc(sizeof(struct number_chunk)); // allocate a new chunk
        cnk->next = NULL;
        for(i=0; i < 1000; i++) { // do the actual reading
            char tmp[20];
            if(fgets(tmp, 20, in) == NULL) { // end of file, leave the read loop
                done = 1;
                break; 
            }
            cnk->nums[i] = atoi(tmp);
        }

        // need to do this so that the last chunk in a file can have less than 1000 numbers in it
        cnk->size = i;

        // add it to the list of chunks to be processed
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cnklst_mutex);
        cnk->next = next_chunk;
        next_chunk = cnk;
        pthread_cond_signal(&data_available); // wake a waiting worker
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cnklst_mutex);
    }

    fclose(in);
}

struct number_chunk *get_chunk()
{
    struct number_chunk *cnk = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cnklst_mutex);
    //FIXME: if we finish we will never exit the thread
    // need to return NULL when all the work that there will ever be
    // is done, altertitively load everything before starting the workers and 
    // get rid of all the condition variable stuff
    while(next_chunk == NULL)
        pthread_cond_wait(&data_available, &cnklst_mutex);
    cnk = next_chunk;
    if(next_chunk != NULL) next_chunk = next_chunk->next;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cnklst_mutex);
    return cnk;
}
```

The way my workers report the final max prime is to just do it at the end by looking at a single global variable and setting it or not based on the highest prime they found during their run. Obviously you'll need to synchronize for that.

Also note it uses a mutex rather than a semaphore because of the use of `pthread_cond_wait()` If you haven't covered condition variables yet just drop that stuff and load everything before starting your workers.

Also since this is homework, read my code try to understand it then without looking at it again try to write your own.

I would have changed it more but I'm not sure how because it's already basically a really generic producer/consumer example that's missing some bits :P

Another thing to try if you do decide to adopt the same strategy I did and have the loading running in the main thread while the workers work you could add a second condition variable and a counter to limit the number of chunks in the queue and have your workers wake up the main thread if they run out of work.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this problem has plagued me for the last few weeks.  I am terrible at C programming and have struggled all semester, thank you for taking the time to help me out.  I am not sure I understand everything that you are doing there but I am trying to trace it and make sense of it.

Can I do what you did there with the chunks but use my array instead of a file?

Comment: sure, just swap out the array in the struct for the range to work on... but it makes it a bit more awkward to work with. I did it that way so that the loading code doesn't need to care about how many files you're reading.

Comment: We covered almost nothing with struct, I was adding that in because a friend said it would work.  So following your code is tough with my lack of syntactical knowledge.  I find that is my biggest problem with C, I program in PHP and I know exactly what I would like my program to do but I just don't know the syntax well enough.

Comment: One thing to note is my program for some reason is bringing in the number 2147483647 over and over in certain places when reading in the files, I am not sure why this is.

Comment: 2147483647 == 2^31 - 1; You are probably using signed integer which is in <-2^31, 2^31 - 1>. So if you are looking for larger primes than that, you should use `unsigned long` instead of `int`. `Unsigned long` is in <0, 2^64 - 1>. If this is still not enough for you, use [gmp](http://gmplib.org/). The numbers I specified are the most common value ranges for the types I described. This may vary depending on platform. If you wanna know, what YOUR integer/long etc can fit, you can ask for it by `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(long)` etc.

Comment: What should be safer to use is `stdint` library which defines types like `uint64_t` which guarantees 64bit variable. So back to your problem, your int is evidently of size 4B. Try writing a dummy program that only has in main `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long)); printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long)); printf("%d\n", sizeof(uint64_t));` Remember to `#include <stdint.h>` You can choose any of the types that says that it's size is 8 and replace any variable definitions that hold your primes with that type.

Comment: You fixed what? Should I consider this solved or you still need some help?

Comment: I have updated what i'm doing, I need to just get my threads to run, but only thread 0 is running and executing.  I want the semaphores to allow the thread's to update the global in the function.